# completely disable the WordPress auto updates

Tags: wordpress

My question is simple because I am new to WordPress, I know how to completely disable the WordPress auto updates.

But let me know what are the disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: i.e. if there is some safety bug and you don't update the system, your data are in danger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);
```

For more information take a look at the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates).